# How do I write an Action Query that changes the data in its data source or creates a new table?

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to know how do I write an Action Query that changes the data in its data source of create a new table for SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Hello J. and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not the kind of question to ask here, because it doesn't require to fix some code problems (in code that you already have written), which is what people are hoping to find when searching this site. You have created "Action Queries" in MS Access, right? Microsoft provides a really good documentation on the UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE and SELECT INTO statements, just type these words in the search field of your browser (in conjunction with "SQL Server").

Answer (score 0):

They're two separate actions. You change the data with an UPDATE query. You create a table with a CREATE TABLE statement, then insert data with an INSERT query.

It's not good practice to create tables on the fly, unless you, for some reason, need temporary tables. You may need to elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish.